# DynamoDb delete non-existent item does not fail, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am deleting a non-existing record from the dynamodb table using `dynamoDbMapper.delete(object)` which uses default DynamoDBDeleteExpression

I was expecting some sort of exception to arise since the record is absent from the DB but it does nothing. It does not even have a return type which could tell if the delete was successful or failure. Is there a way to add a delete expression or something which will make my delete throw an exception if the item is absent from the db?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is by design:

> Unless you specify conditions, the DeleteItem is an idempotent operation; running it multiple times on the same item or attribute does not result in an error response.

FROM:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the command to fail if the item isn't present?

Comment: yes you can use condition expression to achieve that - 

aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id": {"N": "id123"}}' \
    --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(Price)"

Comment: @ManthanJamdagni Woulnd't you use attribute_exists() instead because you only want the deletion to take place if the attribute exists and to fail if it doesn't, as the OP says?

Answer (score 11):

It's possible to utilize ReturnValues to determine if delete did anything or not. If `ReturnValues.Attributes` is empty, it means delete didn't find a record to delete, and you can throw an error in this case. Example in JavaScript:

```
async function deleteWithThrowIfNotExists() {
  const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const parameters = {
    Key: {
      user: 'john'
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_OLD',
    TableName: 'users'
  };
  const response = await dynamo.delete(parameters).promise();
  if (!response.Attributes) {
    throw new Error('Cannot delete item that does not exist')
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can first load the item, and if item doesn't exists you can throw exception otherwise delete it.

Comment: I would prefer not to waste an extra RCU for this operation and would go for condition expression to achieve the same - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.AdvancedComparisons.

Comment: Bad approach, please don't do this. It will work, but it also generates a completely unnecessary query (and thus unnecessary costs and delays)

Comment: This has a race condition between your two requests, where another client machine can create/update/delete the item between requests